# Fastest way to create random vectors for benchmarking

Tags: c++, benchmarking, stdvector

So, I'm just playing around implementing some sorting algorithms in C++, but I'm finding it irritating to benchmark them at the moment, due to the length of time it takes to not run the algorithm, but to create the input data. I currently test each length of input (1000, 2000, ...) 10 times, to gain a somewhat averaged time. For each of these 10 times, I create a new random `vector` of the correct length, by doing:

```
    // Each of the 10 times.
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        A.clear();

        // 'i' is the current input size.
        for(int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            A.push_back(rand() % 10000);
        }

        // Other stuff
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Should I be bothering to cap the rand() at 10000, or is that just my OCD brain liking round numbers? (I.e., could that modulo operation actually be taking a serious amount of time when you consider it's performed up to - at the moment - 10,000 for each loop of the 10.) Alternatively, should I really create a new vector each time I run the sort? I've been doing so because I felt that it's possible that a created vector might be biased, and so if that one was generated and then used 10 times the answer might be quite off...

Comment: I can't imagine the modulo being relevant compared to the random number generation. However, it's easy to test that: just remove it and measure. (You do test release build, don't you?)

Comment: Sorting algorithms *really* like random data.  You are not creating an accurate benchmark, use *real* data.

Comment: @Hans Passant Can you give examples of where I can find some nice pre-made real data? Because I'm afraid I wouldn't know where to start when considering how to generate *real* data... especially when I try to even imagine how many different types there are (very preordered, very chaotic, etc), and which would be more common...

Comment: If you want to be _really_ thorough, `std::next_permutation()` is your friend. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Yup, there are a few things you might want to do here to help speed things up. 
As mentioned before, reserving space in the std::vector and then assigning values to the known elements, is faster. Also, pre incrementing ( ++var instead of var++ ) is faster when using non optimized compilers. Just for the sake of keeping your code fast, no matter who builds it, you might want to consider doing that from now on. As far as memory goes, you may find it trivial, but when I use known sizes that are unsigned, and not unreasonably large, I use unsigned short's for my for loops.

About the modulo, however. You might want to not use it, if you don't need it. Depending on the data type held in the vector, your results should wrap if they go above the maximum storage capacity of the type.

I don't know off hand if it eats up more processing power having variables wrap, and if it does, I'm still not sure if its a less expensive operation then preforming modulo. Might want to run some speed tests with known sizes before going with rand.

```
    A.reserve(i * i);
    for(unsigned short j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {            
        for(unsigned short k = 0; k < i; ++k) 
            A[k + (i*10)] = rand();                
        // Other stuff
    }
```

**Edit**

Very small change to note: The loop is going only 10 times, so you might as well use an unsigned char, rather than a short. On Win32 at the very least, it takes half the memory.

```
    A.reserve(i * i);
    for(unsigned char j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {            
        for(unsigned char k = 0; k < i; ++k) 
            A[k + (i*10)] = rand();                
        // Other stuff
    }
```

Comment: readability is more important than performance "no matter who builds it". post-increment is as fast as pre-increment for 20 years now!

Comment: Haha, yes you're right of course. I was in college when I wrote this, it looks pretty silly in hindsight the level of insanity I tried to go through for microseconds on compilers I didn't have and didn't even know how to profile for. I do prefer pre-incremental stylistically and that's what my colleagues do though. But yes, absolutely focus on readability/debugability and all that good stuff. For style preferences just stick to what the original author used or a project standards doc if you're writing new code. That's what I'd tell a novice if one asked me today.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from cplusplus.com (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), which offers a very useful hint:

"Reallocations may be a costly operation in terms of performance, since they generally involve the entire storage space used by the vector to be copied to a new location. Therefore, whenever large increases in size are planned for a vector, it is recommended to explicitly indicate a capacity for the vector using member function `vector::reserve`."

Using `vector::reserve` will almost certainly give a performance increase in your case.

EDIT: You could try using `random_shuffle` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) to shuffle your vector once it's been created (apparently, `random_shuffle`is linear in the number of elements).

Comment: It will almost certainly only do so for the first run. I don't think implementations are really dismissing their capacity on `clear()`. If they would, we wouldn't need the swap trick.

Comment: @sbi: thanks for pointing that out, you're absolutely right, `clear()` won't shrink the vector and apparently, not even `shrink_to_fit()` definitely will (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664051/why-is-shrink-to-fit-non-binding).

Answer (score -1):

I create one, take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc < 2){
        printf("No arguments found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int maxi;
    maxi = atoi(argv[1]);
    int * a;
    a = new int [5];

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << maxi;
    printf(ss.str());
    printf("\n");
}
```