# Will a std::vector's capacity ever be reduced?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, std

[C++14 final working draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf?raw=true) makes the following comment about `std::vector`:

> Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) says:

> The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and contracted as needed.

And [Wikipedia entry for Dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) says:

> C++'s `std::vector` and Rust's `std::vec::Vec` are implementations of dynamic arrays

So I think that a vector should automatically reduce its capacity when its capacity is much larger than its size. I wrote the following code to check my assumption:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> v = {};

  cout << "initialization" << endl;
  cout << "  capacity: " << v.capacity() << endl;
  cout << "  size: " << v.size() << endl;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) 
    v.push_back(i);

  cout << "after inserting a lot of elements" << endl;
  cout << "  capacity: " << v.capacity() << endl;
  cout << "  size: " << v.size() << endl;

  v.erase(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 10000);
  cout << "after erasing a lot of elements" << endl;
  cout << "  capacity: " << v.capacity() << endl;
  cout << "  size: " << v.size() << endl;

  v.push_back(9);

  cout << "after inserting another element" << endl;
  cout << "  capacity: " << v.capacity() << endl;
  cout << "  size: " << v.size() << endl;
}
```

I used `g++ -std=c++14 code.cc` to compile the code. And running the resulted `a.out` produces the following output. I am using macOS Mojave.

```
initialization
  capacity: 0
  size: 0
after inserting a lot of elements
  capacity: 16384
  size: 10000
after erasing a lot of elements
  capacity: 16384
  size: 1
after inserting another element
  capacity: 16384
  size: 2
```

So it seems that a `std::vector` does not reduce its capacity even if its capacity is much larger than its size.

Will a `std::vector` ever reduce its capacity?
So are there some conditions to trigger the reduction of its capacity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is shrink\_to\_fit non-binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664051/why-is-shrink-to-fit-non-binding)

Comment: just my though, but if a vector ever reach certain `size()`. then it's reasonable to assume it would reach that again. and do the reduce of `capacity` is just a waste of time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the accepted answer. Will the vector shrink at some point as space optimization or it never shrinks? Also your erase() function in the above code is given with v.begin() + 10000, isn't is beyond the range of the vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I think that a vector should reduce its capacity when its capacity is much larger than its size.

Firstly, the standard would have to specify what "capacity is much larger than its size" would mean. That would limit the choices that implementations currently have over the reallocation strategy.

Secondly, if reducing the capacity required re-allocating and moving all the remaining elements. This means that *all* iterators may be invalidated by an erase, which limits safe usage.

Currently, erase states

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator.

Thirdly, a vector is just as likely to reach it's high watermark of capacity again as it is to remain small for a long time.

You would be making the usage worse for a number of valid scenarios, for the *dubious* benefit of releasing a large allocation. Modern virtual memory systems deal fine with old allocations sticking around strictly longer than neccecary.

> So are there some conditions to trigger the reduction of its capacity?

Yes, `shrink_to_fit` is an *explicit request* to do what you want. If you *do* desire it to reallocate to a smaller size, you can ask for that. Other usages, which would be harmed by shinks, are unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

If `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` in your implementation doesn't do what you want to achieve (since it just makes a *non-binding* request for reducing the vector's capacity), you could consider applying the [*swap-to-fit* idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Shrink-to-fit) on your vector `v`:

```
std::vector<int> v;

// ...

{
   std::vector<int> tmp(v); // create a copy of vector v
   tmp.swap(v);
   // vector tmp goes out of scope --> tmp is destroyed
}
```

Or simply as an one-liner:

```
std::vector<int>(v).swap(v);
```

This idiom consists of creating a *temporary* vector object, which is made of the elements of the original vector `v`, and then *swapping* this resulting temporary with the original vector `v`.

Applying this idiom exchanges the capacities of the resulting temporary vector and `v`.
This will result in `v` having a lower capacity if the resulting temporary has a lower capacity than the original vector `v`. This is likely to be the case if `v.size()` was much lower than `v.capacity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends under which operations. If you include all of them, then yes.

See [vector.capacity]p9 (`shrink_to_fit`):

> *Remarks*: `shrink_to_fit` is a non-binding request to reduce `capacity()` to `size()`. [ *Note*: The request is non-binding to allow latitude for implementation-specific optimizations. — *end note* ] ...

and [vector.capacity]p10 (`swap`):

> *Effects*: Exchanges the contents and `capacity()` of `*this` with that of `x`.

In other words, with `shrink_to_fit()`, you may reduce the capacity. With `swap()`, as long as you are able to create another `vector` with less `capacity()`, you are guaranteed to be reducing *your* `capacity()` if you  `swap()` them (but note that the "original" capacity, i.e. the one which is now that of the other object, is not reduced per se).

---

Quick note regarding:

> So I think that a vector should reduce its capacity when its capacity is much larger than its size. I wrote the following code to check my assumption:

In order to reduce the `capacity()`, implementations would need (typically) to allocate memory (and move/copy the elements and deallocate the original storage), which is a very expensive operation that nobody wants when erasing elements.

On top of that, if your program then reaches again its new `capacity()` (which is likely, because you already did before), the process has to be repeated again.